# How to use user groups in Qweb in Odoo to control views?

Tags: odoo, qweb

Is there any way to control views depending on user groups in Qweb?

I try to change the visibility of the "new message" button in the chatter. The button should only be visible if the user is in debug mode.

```
<templates>
<t t-extend="mail.Chatter">
    <t t-jquery="button[class='btn btn-sm btn-primary o_chatter_button_new_message']" t-operation="replace">
        <button type="button" groups="base.group_no_one" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary o_chatter_button_new_message"
            title="Send a message">
                New message
            </button>
    </t>
</t>
```

The attribute `groups="base.group_no_one"` doesn't work. I also tried `t-if` conditions but got no success.

Comment: did you used this tags with in div tag group with group